# FlutterFire Firebase class not recognised in firebase_core package

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have installed `firebase_core: ^0.4.4` in Flutter, and the docs ask you to initialise your app by calling `Firebase.initializeApp()` - docs here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview

The issue is that the `Firebase` class is not recognised in the `package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart` package.

Firstly, do you still need to initialise the app? No other documentation (Firebase docs) mentions this.

I did noticed that a class called `FirebaseApp` is recognised, and seems to be a singleton. I wonder if it is just loaded lazily instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a newer version of firebase_core will solve your problem. Try using `firebase_core: "0.5.0+1"`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the firebase_core package, try using the packages that are made for a specific firebase product. For example, if you want to use cloud firestore, use the cloud_firestore package.

Comment: Yea, I guess the Firebase app is initialised lazily behind the scenes when you do something with the other packages.

Answer (score 0):

In the current flutter (3.3.8 for me), one needs to use FirebaseFirestore, e.g. FirebaseFirestore.instance.  There is no 'Firebase' class any more.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using VS Code, it may load an older version of the firebase core library.

In my environment, I reopened VS Code and it worked.